# prerequisites to algorithms and then to python and Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, algorithms, javascript

I spent the last 5 months studying full-stack web development using the MERN stack, that is (MongoDB, Express, React and NodeJs). Now that I have seen the full picture of what I would be doing everyday, I kind of lost interest in the career due to many factors that are not the very subject of my question, after a little research to find an alternative, I came to realize that data science and AI have a huge potential down the road plus a far more interesting challenges to face on a daily basis, But I can't just disregard what I have done already and start a new studying path, simply because I need money, and so, doing what I am doing now, I am expecting to land at least a front-end job in about 1-2 months, so I have a plan to work as a web developer during 2019 and then transition to data science by 2020, Now, I wanna study Algorithms that can I use in both worlds, currently in Javascript, and later in python or R, But I am not really sure how much knowledge of algorithms and data structure do I need, I found a couple of courses from MIT OCW about algorithms one of which is called introduction to algorithms in this [link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/index.htm), then in the course description It is mentioned that there is a mathematical prerequisite course called Mathematics for computer science, find it [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/). 
up until this point things make sense to me without problems, but then in this course's description I found out that it has another prerequisite course called sigle variable calculus, which suggested a strong high school mathematics skills to take it, Now, this is very intimidating, I was hoping to find one course that could provide me with the mathematical foundation upon which I could study algorithms and then statistics later on. so, I would appreciate if someone can give me directions regarding the following:

1. Do I really need to study all the math courses that MIT suggested to get started with algorithms ?
2. the algorithms course that I left a link to above is actually part one of three courses about algorithms, how many of them do I need to know considering what I am trying to accomplish ?

thanks very much for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, If you want to become data science what should you focus on is not math for computer science but the statistics associated with multi-dimension mathematics such as probability, calculus, matrix, linear algebra as the foundation. There is no free pass to get of this knowledge, so trying to get all the mathematics course as fast as possible is the short-run determination that can ruin your math life in long-term as many of programmer try to fit in the demand by learning python and R for data scientist but practically not skilled enough. If you really believe in your goal don't make it rush, the mastery comes with effort and time. MIT course is good but what is better than a course is "determinant" and reading a highly related book instead.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so what I understood from you is that I should take enough time to acquire the adequate skills necessary to ML and AI, I understand that perfectly,  but that still didn't answer the question that is how much math do I need to study algorithms and how deep should I dive in, in the ocean of algorithms and data structures to be a better Javascript developer for now at least